# How to calculate direct proportionality with logarithms and constant terms added

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the equation:

$$y=a-b-c\log(x)$$

How do I calculate how $y$ scales with $x$?

This is simple without the logarithms. For example:

$$y=a+bx$$

$$y=b(\frac{a}{b}+x)$$

$$y\propto(\frac{a}{b}+x)$$

But how do I do this when logarithms are included?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem if Logarithm is included? If you want to Remove Logarithm, you can use Taylor's expansions.